# Check for missing files in two directories and their respective subdirectories

Tags: files, terminal, directory

Folder `alpha` has one subfolder, and files in both root and in subfolder.

Folder `beta` has 25 subfolders with files in them.

How would I compare the file contents of `alpha` and `beta`, checking for difference in files?

Comment: Have you tried `diff`?

Comment: I looked into it, but couldn't find how to include all subfolders files. Or does it suffice comparing the two main folders and it automatically include everything inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the file and directory names don't have newlines in them:

```
diff  <(cd alpha ; find . -type f) <(cd beta; find . -type f)
```

The `find` commands list the files in the directories the `cd` changed to and the `diff` compares the listings. Output looks like:

```
1c1,2
< ./b/c/file.x
---
> ./b/c/file.d
> ./b/c/file.e
```

with `<` indicating files only in alpha and `>` only in beta

Comment: I'm comparing folders with ~ 30 000 files, and the file difference will be in the hundreds. Is there any way to only output the missing files?

Comment: @Numbers, updated the answer.

Comment: "find: illegal option -- t"

Comment: @Numbers There was a . missing after the first find. (The one from GNU findutils doesn't seem to care about it).